# Do you have to wait for a child thread to finish before you leave the thread that started it?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So lets say you create a thread in main (thread 1). This thread takes in some input from a file and creates multiple other threads (thread 2...etc) to process something. Do you have to exit the other threads (thread 2...) before exiting thread 1? If so how would I go about waiting for all the threads spawned by thread 1 to finish?

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: "By having main() explicitly call pthread_exit() as the last thing it does, main() will block and be kept alive to support the threads it created until they are done." Does this hold true for other threads that are not main? So if I have pthread_exit() at the end of thread 1 it will wait for the other threads?

Comment: @mashedtatoes That is incoherent if applied to other threads. Other threads *cannot* return from `main`, nor can `main` block in other threads. So it wouldn't make any sense. If other threads call `pthread_exit`, they exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to wait for the other threads to exit, in most situations.  The whole point of threads is to start a sub-process of sorts that's largely independent of the thread that started it.

If you don't care how/when the thread will exit, though, you should usually detach the thread.  Otherwise, it'll assume you care about its exit status, and it will sit there taking up resources -- even after it exits -- until some other thread joins it to retrieve the exit status.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just learned about creating multiple processes and now i'm learning about threads so i got a bit confused with my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

There are no parent/child relationships among threads. Threads are all peers. It makes no difference which thread started another thread, all the threads are equal parts of the process that contains them.

The special rule about calling `pthread_exit` from `main` only applies because returning from `main` terminates the *process*. There is no such concern with other threads -- they could only terminate the process by calling `exit` or a similar function.

Note that you should *either* join or detach each thread. You can detach all your threads and then you never have to worry about joining them -- they'll just run to completion and then clean themselves up.